# ReactJs rendering a nested value in an array of objects

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to iterate/map through an array of objects and use nested values, but I cannot seem to get it to work. If i pass in a simple array

```
const people = [
 { name: "joe", id: "1" },
 { name: "mary", id: "2" }
];
```

to my ShowList component

```
const ShowList = (props) => {
 const {people} = props;
 return ( renderPeep(people))
};

const renderPeep = (people) => (
 <ul>
  {people.map((peep, index) => (
    <li key={index}>{peep}</li>
   ))}
</ul>
 )
```

I get a list of both values:

```
joe1
mary1
```

and both dot notation and bracket dont work (`{peep.name}` ) to just list names. is the map function causing us to lose keys info on the underlying objects? what am I missing?

Comment: nope. you should be able to do `peep.name` or `peep.id`.

Comment: yep. I just realized I succumbed to the combinatorial problem of Javascript- every library addition completely changes everything, i.e. deciding between 5 libraries means theres 32 different implementations I need to learn. In my case, I wasn't actually passing in the people object, i was passing it to Immutable js fromJS function. So, it was `peep.get('name')` that I needed.

Comment: make sense if you are using immutable.js

Answer (score 1):

Change `<li key={index}>{peep}</li>` to `<li key={index}>{peep.name}</li>`. Inside the `array#map` you are getting an object and you can access `name` using dot notation or bracket notation.

Alternatively, you can also use destructuring:

```
const renderPeep = (people) => (
 <ul>
  {people.map(({name}, index) => (
    <li key={index}>{name}</li>
   ))}
</ul>
)
```

```js
const people = [
 { name: "joe", id: "1" },
 { name: "mary", id: "2" }
];

const ShowList = (props) => {
 const {people} = props;
 return (renderPeep(people));
};

const renderPeep = (people) => (
 <ul>
  {people.map((peep, index) => (
    <li key={index}>{peep.name}</li>
   ))}
</ul>
)

ReactDOM.render(
  <ShowList people={people} />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id='app'></div>
```

Comment: Actually this is the exact problem the OP mentioned, that `peep.name` is not working as expected: "_and both dot notation and bracket dont work ({peep.name} )..._"